# Store information about the type of an object

Tags: c++, rtti

I need to store the type of an object in a class.
This would look like:

```
template<class T>
class box
{
private:

    type_info type;
    T data;
}
```

The reason why I need to store the type information is complex to explain, anyway I would know if this is possibile in C++.
When i try to compile an instruction like:

```
type=typeid(data);
```

I get a syntax error:
No matching for initialization of 'std::type_info'
So it seems like type_info hasn't the constructor with no arguments.Is possibile then in some way, to memorize the type of an object into a data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

typeinfo is noncopyable - its constructors and assignment operator are private (in C++11 they are flagged deleted).  you're probably after something along these lines:

```
template<class T>
class box
{
public:
    box() : data(), type(typeid(data))
    {
    }
private:
    T data;
    const type_info& type;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can take a pointer from the object returned by the typeid expression:

```
const std::type_info* const type = &typeid( data );
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to take the name of the class/object and store it:

`std::string name = typeid(data).name();`

Comment: On some systems, typeid(x).name() is 'b' for bools, 'd' for doubles, 'Ss' for std::strings, 'h' for unsigned ints, etc. So you'll have to decipher that output somewhat.